# jQuery Checkbox with UnChecked Event Handler in SharePoint 2010 List Form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, jquery, list-form

I need to write a javascript/jquery code that make the checkbox if unchecked do not put a validation of a textbox and if checked the text box is validated for null or empty in my SP 2010 list form.
 I have written code for  checking the checkbox, and it works but when I uncheck the checkbox which is already checked, I am not able to get the value or trigger the event.
   I added this code within a content editor web part.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#ctl00_m_g_97fe2364_4242_487c_9dbc_8d1547697f5e_
   ctl00_ctl05_ctl17_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00").
     change(function() 
      {
     var checked0 = $(this).is(":checked");
     if (checked0) 
     {
    //      alert('orc bi epm is checkedd111');

     $("input[title='ORCBIEPM']").focus(); 
     $("input[Title='ORCBIEPM']").css("background-color","#FE2E2E"); 
     ORCBIEPMchecked =true;  
    }
   else
    {
      ORCBIEPMchecked =false;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
  if (document.getElementById('xxx').checked) 
  {
     // add your stuff here.
  } 
  else 
  {
      // do the stuff here.
  }
```

or just put your code out of $(document).ready(). Since the page might be not loading when you uncheck the checkbox. And hence it might be not hitting the condition and that event.

Comment: you said "just put your code out of $(document).ready(). "                      Can you pls tell, where will I put the code, then. Will the same change click event will work on PreSaveAction function call?

Comment: Yeah it will work on PreSaveAction function but you need to use the different ID there.

Comment: On what basis are you validating, I mean is it on a button click or some other event. If it is on a button click event then call your function on that button click event. Or write the code there in that button click event.